# Create a python list with for-loop and predefined first element

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, syntax

I want to create a list in one line with a `for loop` as follows:

```
a = [i for i in range(0, 5)]
```

In this case `a` is equal to `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. However I would like to predefine the first element (i.e.: `0`) to be `100`.

Therefore I am looking for the syntax for generating `a = [100, 1, 2, 3, 4]` in one line with `for-loop`.

Something like this:

```
a = [100, i for i in range(1, 5)]
```

---

For this example following would work since we know the first value of the iterator `i`, but imagine the first iterator value is unknown or can change with some other data. **How can I code this?**

---

This could work if I know the first value of `i`:

```
a = [100 if i == 0 else i for i in range(0, 5)]
```

since it is unknown or can change, I need to specify somehow the first loop of the `for-loop` in `if-statement`.

Comment: The "this could work..." solution is essentially what you'd end up with, some sort of if statement, just insert the required first value after creation or append it as shown in the given answer below

Comment: @Sayse so no way to specify the first loop of for loop?

Comment: `a = [100] + [i for i in range(5)]`

Comment: yes theres `[100 if idx == 0 else v for idx,v in enumerate(range(5))]` but that will be inefficient compared to insertion

Comment: I'd write this as either `a = [100] + list(range(1, 5))` or `a = [i or 100 for i in range(5)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def create_list(first_val, x, y):
    return [first_val] + [i for i in range(x, y)]
```

If you want to write it without a function, you can:

```
a = [100] + [i for i in range(1, 5)]
```

or, in case the first value is a variable:

```
a = [val] + [i for i in range(1, 5)]
```

Comment: I am not looking for a function. I am looking for a syntax help. or I want to know if it is even possible in one line like in the question.

Comment: I added examples to do it without function.

Comment: Yeah thanks :) that is the syntax I am looking for !!! I will accept the answer in 8 mins